# how to key map an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array as follows

```
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(36) "newyork" ["categoryid"]=> string(1) "4" }                                                                                                                                                                                                            
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(24) "michigun" ["categoryid"]=> string(1) "4" } 
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(27) "canada" ["categoryid"]=> string(1) "5" }             
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(35) "manhatten" ["categoryid"]=> string(1) "5"   
}
```

i want to have a new array where i will have

```
 {"4" => newyork,michigun}
 {"5" => canada,manhatten}
```

.. how can it be done? pls help.

Comment: i tried foreach($key => $value) but i m not sure about the logic.

Comment: you want to add in this array or something else? please paste your desired outcome.Thanks.

Comment: i want a new array which will print {"4" => newyork,michigun}
 {"5" => canada,manhatten}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a loop and build the array -

```
$new = array();
foreach($your_array as $array) {
   if(array_key_exists($array['categoryid'], $new)) { // if categoryid is already set the concatenate the name
       $new[$array['categoryid']] = $new[$array['categoryid']] . ',' . $array['name'];
   } else { // set the name
       $new[$array['categoryid']] = $array['name'];
   }
}
```

Comment: can u explain the  $new[$array['categoryid']] = $new[$array['categoryid']] . ',' . $array['name']; statement ?

Comment: It will concatenate the name with the value which has index of the categoryid.

Answer (score 4):

If don't mind using external lib, it is pretty straightforward with [ouzo-goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies):

```
Arrays::groupBy($array, Functions::extractField('categoryid'));
```

You can go one step further to join names with commas:

```
$result = Arrays::groupBy($array, Functions::extractField('categoryid'));
Arrays::map($result, function($value) {
    return Joiner::on(',')->mapValues(Functions::extractField('name'))->join($value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Uses the PHP 5.4 array syntax: `[]` instead of `array()`

Data

```
$arr = [
  [
    "name" => "newyork",
    "categoryid" => "4"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "michigun",
    "categoryid" => "4"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "canada",
    "categoryid" => "5"
  ],
    [
    "name" => "manhatten",
    "categoryid" => "5"
  ],
];
```

Parse

```
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $el) {
  if (array_key_exists($el['categoryid'], $result)) {
    $result[$el['categoryid']] = $result[$el['categoryid']] . ',' . $el['name'];
  } else {
   $result[$el['categoryid']] = $el['name'];
  }
}


print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array ( [4] => newyork,michigun [5] => canada,manhatten )
```

Comment: This is simply copy and paste of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31692305/2899618)

Comment: Settle down everybody. @b0s3 just beat me to the punch is all.

Comment: @KetkiNimdeo then how does this answer make difference with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31692305/2899618)